# Shell Script - Two Conditions on If Clause

Tags: bash, shell, if-statement

```
#!/bin/bash

(...)

if [ "$1" == "" ] || [ "$2" == "" ] || [ "$3" == "" ] || [ "$4" == "" ] ; then # WORKS!  
echo "Erro  #1: Nao inseriu todos os argumentos necessarios! Tente novamente!"  
echo "Ajuda #1: Lembre-se, ep1.sh [diretoria] [modo] [informação] <nome_do_ficheiro>"

elif [[ "$2" != "contar" || "$2" != "hist" ]] ; then **# THE PROBLEM!!!**  
echo "Erro  #2: O segundo argumento está incorrecto! Tente novamente!"  
echo "Ajuda #2: Use contar ou hist."

elif [[ "$3" != "palavras" || "$3" != "bytes" ]] ; then # CAN'T TEST BECAUSE OF FIRST ELIF  
echo "Erro  #3: O terceiro argumento está incorrecto! Tente novamente!"  
echo "Ajuda #3: Use palavras ou bytes."

(...)

fi
```

So, my problem is in the first `elif`, when the `elif` is False, the program should not enter in the `elif`, but enters.

I do not see what could be the problem.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `&&` not `||`.

```
elif [[ "$2" != "contar" && "$2" != "hist" ]] ; then
```

The reason for switching the operator is [De Morgan's law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws). If you negate

```
if [[ $a == "foo" || $b == "bar" || $c == "baz" ]]
```

you get

```
# negated
if ! [[ $a == "foo" || $b == "bar" || $c == "baz" ]]
```

De Morgan's law says you can distribute the `!` by switching all the `==`'s to `!=`'s and changing `||` to `&&`.

```
# `!` distributed per De Morgan's law
if [[ $a != "foo" && $b != "bar" && $c != "baz" ]]
```

Comment: && is for "and" or "or"?
If it is for "and" I want for "or".

Comment: This was just brought up on meta the other day. http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/273262/canonical-language-agnostic-question-for-ifvar-x-var-y

Comment: Ok, I get it!
Thank you! Works now!